# Como receber os dados de um formulário que tem os nomes de campos repetidos?

Tags: php, html, formulário, crud

Meu projeto final de curso, de maneira bem resumida é um jogo de perguntas e respostas, nesse projeto, tenho a tabela "Alternativas", quando vou realizar o cadastro de perguntas, há quatro campos com o nome de alternativas da seguinte maneira:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Todos os quatro campos estão desta maneira
Envio esses dados para um controlador, a pergunta é:
Como que eu devo receber os dados neste controlador? Devo realizar um foreach?
Uso Javascript no formulário? Ou eu devo mudar o nome de cada campo e recebê-lo separadamente?

Agradeço a ajuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Quando você coloca um "name" com [] colchetes ele é enviado na forma de array para o receptor.

```
//o array
$alternativa = $_POST['alternativa'];
//Retorna o número de elementos da array:
$result = count($alternativa);

for ($i = 0; $i < ($result) ; $i++) {
  echo " Alternativa " . $alternativa[$i] . "<br>";
}
```

> Em relação à estrutura de controle for:

- Declara-se 3 expressões no inicio do for

  - Sendo a 1ª expressão avaliada apenas **uma vez**. Normalmente utilizada para  criação da variável de controle.
  - 2ª expressão é avaliada no inicio de cada  iteração, caso esta expressão retorne falso o looping é encerrado. Podendo ser  considerada a condicional do for.
  - 3ª Expressão é avaliada no final de cada  iteração, normalmente utilizada para alterar o valor da variável de controle.
- Separa-se as expressões utilizando o ;(ponto e virgula).
- O looping é executado enquanto a condição da 2ª  expressão for verdadeira (True)
- Quando  a condição da 2ª expressão for avaliada como falsa (False) o processamento da  rotina é desviado para fora do looping
- O bloco de código referente ao looping deve ser  delimitado por chaves {}
- Endente o código referente ao bloco em 4 espaços  por questões de legibilidade, a como configurar o seu editor de texto para  transformar Tabs em espaços
- Utilizamos um contador para o looping não ficar  um looping infinito, este declarado na 1ª expressão
- Não se esqueça de alterar o valor do contador,  na 3ª expressão, para não cairmos em um looping infinito.